# Import column headers from ASCII file then create function from titles

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ascii

I've written a very large piece of code so I'm trying to condense it as it's very basic and can definitely be shortened.

At the moment I have an ASCII file which has around 30 columns that are ever changing every time I run the program. I'm trying to create a list called:

```
EntrySummary = []
```

At the moment I've manually typed out all the parameters. I.E:

```
for key in Entries1.viewkeys():
    MeanFRH = Entries1[key].hRideF.mean()
```

(There's 30 more of these)
(hRideF is the header of one of the columns and I re-named it to MeanFRH for my own benefit really...)

At the bottom of these 30 lines there's a .append in the form of this:

```
EntrySummary.append({'Turn Number': key, 'Avg FRH': Mean FRH, and so on})

EntrySummary = pd.DataFrame(EntrySummary)
EntrySummary.index = EntrySummary['Turn Number']
del EntrySummary['Turn Number']
```

The problem I have much later on in the code is that if one of these parameters isn't in the ASCII file it throws errors up so I have to keep adding in ones I don't need.

What I'd like to achieve is a way that the code will read the ASCII file column headers and populate the list with a preset formula. I was thinking along the lines of:

```
nColumnname = Entries1[key].Columnname.mean()
```

or

```
n%'s = Entries1[key].%'s.mean()
```

(I'm not even sure if these will work. I haven't made it work yet :/ )

Any advise towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An I right in saying you get a `KeyError` exception?  (Please post your errors) Use exception handling, or `Entries1.get()`

Comment: Sorry I'm not entirely sure what exception handling is? The errors vary completely depending on what I'm trying. I've not seen one like that however.

Comment: OK, tackle one problem at a time.  Post a subset of code and the error you get from that code.  Otherwise we just have to guess.